# Upgrading cassette to give bigger bottom gear

Tags: cassette, upgrades

On e.g. a Giant Stance, can the lowest gear on the cassette be upgraded to a higher tooth count just by only changing that cog?

Comment: It's only worth trying if you have another cassette of similar construction you can salvage the cog from, plus some modest metal-working skills.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the Giant Stance is equipped with Shimano Alivio. That's a fairly low-end groupset and I'm fairly sure you can't replace the cogs one-by-one. In any case, a whole new cassette is only about $20–25.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to separate the individual cogs. This can be done by grinding off the small rivets that hold a subset (typicaly three of the larger cogs) of the cassette together. The rivets don't do anything except make it difficult for you to maintain your cassette by replacing individual cogs, something Shimano probably doesn't want because they make less money. But it's better for you. I have CS-6500 9 speed cassette with custom 13-15-17-19-21-24-27-30-34 gears. You can't buy it like this but you can make it yourself and it's a great way to go. I replace only the worn individual cogs when needed. When the cassette is taken off for cleaning, which I always do when replacing a chain, the cogs and spacers fall off one by one. I return them one-by-one onto the spindle and replace a worn cog if there is one. This is the best way of doing it. Shimano don't want you to do this because it's good for you and bad for them.

Comment: Where do you get single new cogs from?

Comment: Yes this is a problem. I get them from other cassettes. I go for cheap Shimano HG cassettes because the cogs are all the same material anyway. It allows me to have the gearing my way instead of "off-the-shelf" combinations that I don't really like.

Comment: OK. So this is probably only worth doing if the asker also doesn't like the "pre-made" cassettes, since they'll have to buy the new cassette anyway.

Comment: Yes. Or both. They may not like the need to replace the entire cassette if only one or two cogs are worn and, they may like the benefit of alternative gearing. Once the "scrap" cassette has been bought it will provide cogs repeatedly. But usually we wear the same cogs over and over. But still, you get to build up a supply of parts and you get better at it the more you do it. It's more hands-on approach so I noticed that I could take better care overall.

Comment: Another point to consider: Make sure that the rear derailleur has the required tooth capacity and takes the largest cog.

Comment: Aren't the cogs in a cassette designed to work together, with shifting ramps, etc?

Comment: No. The Hyperglide system is a tooth profiling design to smooth the shifting between sprockets but other brands of sprockets can be used instead. Otherwise all sprockets are interchangeable according to Sheldon Brown. Miche sprockets work well but they are not using the Hyperglide tooth profile. All 9 speed Shimano sprockets are Hyperglide (that I know of) and even if they weren't it wouldn't matter.

Comment: But newer speeds (10 and up) limit the user to buying whole new cassettes even if only one or two sprockets are worn. They do this by incorporating the "spider" arrangement which prevents separation of the cassette assembly and is justified by saving micro-grams. Since my weight comprises 80% of the the bike, a design "improvement' such as the spider does nothing for me except limit my ability to maintain autonomy over my gearing choices. That and the fact that thinner chains and sprockets are not best suited to durability causes considerable pause in purchasing.